# Share feature on my Android App

Tags: android, html, whatsapp

We have developed a android app, and we hope to promote the app using simple easy to use features. Connecting to facebook, and hitting like, sharing stories of our facebook page are all too tedious.

We want to make it easy, super easy to share contact information of friends who we can send our app link's too.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject, Tag line");
sharingIntent
    .putExtra(
        android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        "Hi, I am using a neat app, <a href=\"market://details?id=MYPACKAGE\">Taxeeta</a>, to book cabs in my vicinity. No more waiting for call centers to pickup/confirm");
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

The result I am seeing on whatsapp is

> > Hi, I am using a neat app, `<a href=\"market://details?id=MYPACKAGE\">Taxeeta</a>`, to book cabs in my vicinity. No more waiting for call centers to pickup/confirm

I am not seeing a hyperlink.

Edit : I modified type to `text/html` still the hyperlink does not show up.

Comment: sorry!! what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, corrected the question, the hypertext was not showing up.

Comment: are you seeing the hyperlink in other application??

Comment: No, not on gmail too shows without hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling it that the content is plaintext.  Try text/html, so it knows to interpret it.  If that doesn't work, then the app you're sending the intent to doesn't support it.

Comment: You are right, that was it. But still the hyperlink does not show up. Infact with text/html only 2 options show up, Bluetooth and Gmail. They too dont show html hyperlink. I guess it does not support. Upvote, but I rather wait for a correct answer for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

`<a href=\"market://details?id=MYPACKAGE\">Taxeeta</a>`  is Android internal link. You are sharing, so link must be valid is browser. Browsers normally don't understand 'market'.  Try to use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=MYPACKAGE

Comment: I removed the unrelated P.S. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

This works, but only for HTML types of shares. Does not work for WhatsApp. I am still looking for a solution.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Taxeeta") ;
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"market://details?id=com.taxeeta\">Taxeeta</a>"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to share `text/plain` and enter your url in plain text

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"download this funky app at: www.someweb.com/appname");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share this app"));
```

Most of the applications interpret that link correctly (whatsapp, mail...)

The advantage of this solution is, that you can create a `script` at `www.someweb.com/appname` which redirects the user by their `User-Agent`, so android users will be directed to the google play store, ios-users to the apple store, pc to to your app page...